# react-native-fetch-blob link FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, pdf, react-native

How can i Fix my error. i need to display a pdf from my assets folder. im using expo, react native, react-native-pdf

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\kjdelacruz\mobile\cdo-mobile-organizer\node_modules (31ms)
RNFetchBlob checking app version ..
RNFetchBlob detected app version => 6
Add Android permissions => false
react-native-fetch-blob link FAILED
Could not automatically link package :TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:358:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kjdelacruz\mobile\cdo-mobile-organizer\node_modules\react-native-fetch-blob\scripts\prelink.js:29:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3please follow the instructions to manually link the library : https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package

rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
```

Comment: have you done any of the suggestions in the error? as you've shown only the error and not the code that triggers it, the answer is a pineapple

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `rn-fetch-blob` is incompatible with expo. I have dealt with this very problem before with expo and `rn-fetch-blob`.

*"It doesn't work with Expo because Expo doesn't support native module linking. Like you said you'll have to detach from Expo in order to run react-native link react-native-fetch-blob for this to work."*

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html

You will need to use XCode to get it working.

There are a couple threads discussing. No solutions with expo though.

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/97

https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/371